# Invoke web-service in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm writing an application and that application is supposed to talk to a web service. I'm supposed to send a filename to the web service and the web service is supposed to return the (text) contents of that file.

I think I have everything in place, I just really don't know how to write that code or call or what you might call it.

I understand that this is probably pretty straight forward, but I just can't seem to get it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you start by trying to find some good tutorial or coding examples? Then if you have a problem, ask it here.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SOAP web service, JAX-WS is pretty straight forward.
Try the hello world tut here:
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/

If it is REST service, which is more likely now, try this:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/

Comment: tnx, will take a look at the SOAP one